# Convert from UTF-8 to Shift-JIS, in Pascal

Tags: delphi, encoding, pascal

I need the Pascal (Delphi or Free Pascal) function to convert UTF-8 text (e.g. in string) to Shift-JIS (also e.g. in string).

For Shift-JIS => UTF-8 I found the code, [which is here](https://gitlab.com/bunnylin/moonlibs/-/blob/master/sjisutf8.pas). Now I need the backward converter.

I want to add this code to Lazarus library LConvEncoding, so it must be without using 'iconv' or Win32 API, it must be pure Pascal. It may be code in another language if it's easy to rewrite it in Pascal.

Comment: That lovely function is 1119 lines long, though admittedly about 1000 of that are dedicated to tables. Are you expecting someone to cough up something similar for the inverse, in the span of a single SO answer? Is there anything preventing you from taking a crack at it yourself?

Comment: Delphi's `string` has been `UnicodeString` since 2009, so it can't hold UTF-8 or Shift-JIS content, only UTF-16. Perhaps you are thinking of `AnsiString` instead? FreePascal's `string` is still `AnsiString` by default, unless you use `{$modeswitch UnicodeStrings}` or `{$mode DelphiUnicode}`.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer, this code can be made from the Unicode official data:
ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT .

That file tells how to get UTF-16 codes, and next I must convert UTF-16 -> UTF-8, using `UTF8Encode()`.

Comment: So you've read the comments in the code you linked? Good. Also it seems to only handle [JIS X 0208:1997 and not JIS X 0213, because `$85.. $87` is not handled anywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS#Shift_JIS_byte_map).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).